# Xcode Image Z-Index

Tags: iphone, xcode, z-index

is there a way to add a z-index to an image in xcode without having to create a new view. I'm pretty sure you can put the image into a new view and give the view the z-index, but I would rather do it without putting each image in their own views. Also, it must be programmatically, not using Interface Builder. I'm trying to stay away from using IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by z-index you are referring to the order of subviews in a UIView, each subview has its own unique z index, so you'd have to create a new view for each image.